# Problem in linking X11 in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, x11

I use CodeBlocks in Mac to compile my source code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

Display *display;

int main()
{
  display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  XCloseDisplay(display);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling the source code is successfull, but linking to X11 is not successfull.
How to I solve this problem?
Where is libX11 in Mac?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be in /usr/X11R6/lib/.

Answer (score 3):

As Bavarious noted, you'll be looking in /usr/X11/lib (and OS X 10.6.8 uses a symlink to make /usr/X11R6 an option as well). I only used CodeBlocks once, so I couldn't tell you what it requires you do to pass

-L/usr/X11/lib

to gcc.